# Excel VB macro to compare sheets and output results onto another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the macro from here: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20060906110734AA9t2l9 to highlight the diffs. However, when there are 50000 rows, and only 2 of them are different, it's a needle in a haystack problem.

What I would like to be able to do is see the differences in a separate sheet, with the before and after changes side-by-side. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Small addition to your existing code:

```
Sub Compare_Sheets()

Dim v1,v2
Dim diffRow as long

Set From_WS = Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set To_WS = Workbooks("Book2").Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set diffWS = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Diff")

diffRow = 1

With From_WS.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    Total_Rows = .Rows.Count
    Total_Columns = .Columns.Count
End With

For Rows_Counter = 1 To Total_Rows
For Column_Counter = 1 To Total_Columns
v1 = Trim(LCase(From_WS.Cells(Rows_Counter, Column_Counter).Value))
v2 = Trim(LCase(To_WS.Cells(Rows_Counter, Column_Counter).Value)) 

If v1 <> v2 Then
    From_WS.Cells(Rows_Counter, Column_Counter).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    To_WS.Cells(Rows_Counter, Column_Counter).Interior.ColorIndex = 5

    With diffWS.Rows(diffRow)
        .Cells(1).value=From_WS.Cells(Rows_Counter, Column_Counter).Address()
        .Cells(2).value = v1
        .Cells(3).value= v2
        diffRow = diffRow + 1
    End With

End If

Next Column_Counter
Next Rows_Counter

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, I just tested with Sheet1 and sheet2 of the current workbook and it doesn't seem to work. Total_Rows and Total_Columns evaluates to 1. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: This works nicely though... http://www.exceltip.com/st/Compare_two_worksheets_using_VBA_in_Microsoft_Excel/477.html

Comment: Well, I only refactored the code from the post the OP pointed to, so I assumed that was working for them.  It does depend on both sheets having the same data laid out starting at A1...

Comment: To access the workbook containing the running code, you can use `ThisWorkbook` directly, or if you need the actual name then `ThisWorkbook.Name`.  If you want the currently-active workbook then use `ActiveWorkbook`